# How to write my own filter in logstash(In special usage)

Tags: python, encryption, filter, logstash

all

Now i want to ship event from remote server to center server to collect and parse logs.Originally i use pyinotify, but I found logstash is an excellent tool to doing this.

But i have a question, The event message is bing encrypted, so i want to decode the message during the fliter process. The filter could be writtern by python or java? The decode process need the othe third part package, like rc4, argparse, urlparse and the others, how could i do?

I find the document in logstash.net site ,but it's too simple, and i still don't konw how to do.

Thanks very much.

More message :
Because the log from the remote server is eccrypted by rc4, i need to decode first and then parse the log.The log is like this :
`1418572797.786 0 112.8.84.86 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 283 GET http://statlog.cc.netease.com/query?c=AUDIO&ts=20141214235959&sig=-1056308330&data=JaaBbq_g_-yBWXkRYRTTPm5mCqMvSGNmVUeftZhFmIqEXPuxu4co4vRupZXrvGXAx2zgTgJUsQuR0X7dtuKSkOK_gzG8S-spplElIfmpoB1g3LcUF-rh8IGFxtmZlSkmU5vxOG8jmmbwe-MTijNgv6Clgh5scBKmWpzkv8dtFGop58paHL8j7W_RL6KkWqHaieADsJGNy4E_qHKfTljG0bl5AEFX - NONE/- - "-"`

Comment: Have you considered using logstash-forwarder to ship the logs?

Comment: @AlainCollins: What difference would that make?

Comment: Who or what encrypts the message? And why? Filter plugins are, like the rest of Logstash, written in Ruby.

Comment: @MagnusBäck The log from is the remote server have been encrypted already. if i use the third part lib of ruby, would it be work in logstash, as it's running by jruby.

Comment: @MagnusBäck, since the OP is looking to write some code to *decode* the message, perhaps they wrote the code to *encode* the message.  If so, maybe they could throw that away and use logstash-forwarder, which provides the encryption.

Comment: @AlainCollins: Okay, although Logstash also supports the same protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write the code to do the decryption of the message in ruby rather than python/java you could use the [ruby filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/ruby) which allows you to run ruby code in the logstash filter.

It looks like only the message part is encrypted, so you would probably want to grok out that encrypted message in to a field, then pass that to the ruby to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it,
just as the http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/extending/
use ruby to write your code ,it could import the third part package .and everything will be ok .